# How I can travel with a 576Wh single‑cell lithium‑ion battery (or 12Ah with 48V) from mainland France to Guadeloupe in the French West Indies?

Tags: air-travel, france, batteries, atlantic-ocean

As part of my work and with electricity becoming completely unreliable in Guadeloupe with power plants being shut down leaving mostly renewable (leaving street lights literally blinking and tap water not constantly running), I’m planning to come with a 25Kg metal device powered by an internal lithium‑ion battery.
[Corsair](https://www.flycorsair.com/) (the only company serving flights between my city in mainland and Guadeloupe) told me outright I can bring the device with me as a luggage only if the internal battery is removed.

While I don’t mind spending 3 hours in order to remove the battery with bringing the required tooling to put it back once I would have arrived, the problem is all the parcel services I found treat such sendings as dangerous prohibited goods.
*Though*, **I don’t think** getting it in Guadeloupe is **something impossible** : I bought it online from a Chinese seller. It was sent to my home by plane using [菜鸟网络](https://global.cainiao.com/detail.htm?spm=a2d0j.7922267.0.0.2ed638837kXHHW&mailNoList=13289600269358) and handled in France by http://www.dpd.com **with the content of the parcel clearly written in large characters on the cardboard**.
Though **buying a new one isn’t an option :** not only because of shortages nobody is selling spare parts, including the battery (I recently had to pay 150€ for 3D printing a part from the original broken one), but the sellers I found including the original one **aren’t shipping to French overseas as well as [Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco) and [Andorre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra) in mainland**.

I was also unable to find how to open an account on https://www.dpd.com as an individual nor I was able to find a said dpd office…

**Please also note legally that Guadeloupe is a region like another region in mainland so it’s almost legally like taking the plane between 2 cities in mainland**, but with the Atlantic ocean in practice.

*My point is if sending the battery as a parcel, I would need the company along with their exact offer name* so that their answer wouldn’t be `no you can’t send it with us`.
**Otherwise, I kept the original cardboard, so it’s not about finding what needs to be put on it legally**.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "As part of my work" are you employed by a company or are you acting as an independent contractor, or are you just going to Guadeloupe because you want to?

Comment: @PeterM more exactly I was required to not stay in mainland but did not with the argument everything happened on a remote basis, so I have to bear the consequences of it instead of the college along with the company (apprentice).

Comment: OK .. I was trying to see if this was really someone else's problem and not your problem.

Comment: @PeterM it could have been the problem of someone else, but I chose to save the price of 2 plane tickets…

Comment: Would sea transport be an option?

Comment: @Willeke it would be too long in order to get it on time… The plan was also to send the goods before my departure next week… Though, I might be interested in a later case : but then the problem is finding a parcel delivery service not using planes for shipping parcels to Guadeloupe…

Comment: Lithium batteries from a Chinese source - what could possibly go wrong? Are deep cycle batteries available in Guadeloupe? Pretty easy to get far more amp-hours that way, plus a controller that takes solar input.

Comment: Probably it is cheaper to buy a new battery in Guadalupe. Special cargo are too expensive. Ev. ask Air France (cargo branch).

Comment: @JonCuster this is for an Internal battery. It has to have a specific shape and proprietary connector.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi **didn’t you read the question** ? It’s not possible to buy them here or get them delivered there. Moreover, the battery is only 30cm long, so definitely a small parcel.

Answer (score 3):

Wh (watt-hours, i.e. watts multiplied by hours), not W/h (watts per hour, which is meaningless).

The IATA rules for lithium batteries transported by passengers are here: https://www.iata.org/contentassets/6fea26dd84d24b26a7a1fd5788561d6e/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf

Clearly you are way beyond what is allowed, you need to ship them as cargo (or make many separate trips if you have many individual cells each under the limits).

Cargo regulations are here: https://www.iata.org/contentassets/05e6d8742b0047259bf3a700bc9d42b9/lithium-battery-guidance-document-2021.pdf

It’s clearly possible to ship Lithium batteries, you just have to follow the rules. Individual carriers (DHL, UPS, FedEx, DPD…) have their own rules which derive from the IATA rules, you’ll have to check with each one of them for specifics, but mostly it involves:

- batteries being certified
- the state of load of the batteries
- careful packaging according to the rules
- correct labelling
- prior notification
- use of the appropriate service

Such batteries may not necessarily be able to be carried on passenger services which also carry cargo, so depending on the destination this may be an issue (that’s why prior notification is important). Most carriers have dedicated cargo flights to mainland France, I’m not sure they have the same to Guadeloupe.

It’s also quite possible that such cargo will only be transported for business customers rather than individuals.

Note that the fact that it’s still France doesn’t change much. The issue is air transport (anywhere in mainland France they could get by truck if air transport wasn’t available — this is obviously not an option for Guadeloupe).

Comment: Went to FedEx : their word : No ! Went to LaPoste : their word : No ! Went to ᴅʜʟ : their word : No ! Wasn’t able to find a ᴜᴘꜱ or ᴅᴘᴅ office. **I know air cargo is possible, but the problem is where do I pay for sending the battery as a parcel** ? I would also need their exact offer name available in France so that answer isn’t that I can’t.

Comment: For UPS for instance see https://www.ups.com/assets/resources/media/fr_FR/pack_ship_batteries.pdf page 5. If your cells are stand-alone that UN3480, which requires a special contract for hazardous materials (if at all possible). If mounted in equipment it’s UN3481, then see the document linked above for IATA regulations (sorry, too lazy to read them again at this hour to see the rules in your case). But again chances are that you’ll require a business contract with them to process them.

Comment: But it doesn’t say where such a contract can be signed… A parcel is deposited in an office…

Comment: You may also need a business contract to even be able to speak to someone who won’t just reply “no” whenever you say “lithium battery”, just because they don’t want to have to down a tube of aspirin to understand the relevant regulations.

Comment: I recommend you start by reading the IATA regulations and find exactly which case you are in, what documents and labels are required, what classification and notification is needed. Then search for “lithium” on each carrier’s site to see their specific rules. Make sure you have aspirin at hand.

Comment: When even the local companies in the same business regarding the device tell you they failed to find a way for shipping anything, be sure the word is it’s not simple. In the case of ᴜᴘꜱ, franchisees say that such signing of a contract for a business doesn’t exist even if you prove them otherwise… **The only thing which would allow to change their mind is by telling them under which offer name it can be sent** (like `collissimo` or `Chronopost` in the case of La Poste) not by just pointing to a random paper stating a contract can be signed.

Comment: **Otherwise, I kept the original cardboard, so it’s not about finding what needs to be put on it.** Compared to other countries, France is business wise the country of `No`, where if someone don’t want something which is possible, there’s no money amount high enough to change it… Even in the case of the smallest companies.

Comment: Local franchises or drop points are not the appropriate venues for this type of contracts, they are just local businesses having a contract with the big companies and can't make any decision. Business contracts are handled at the corporate level, you can even sign up on the website and they will call you back. But unless you are a reputable business, the chance that they will let you ship an essentially unknown hazardous material is slim.

Comment: @xngtng the point of contact for France in the case of ᴜᴘꜱ and ᴅᴘᴅ isn’t on their website… I have some idea in mind about which small business would do it for me.

Comment: @xngtng so I don’t have anyone to contact at ᴜᴘꜱ and ᴅᴘᴅ…

Comment: https://contact.dpd.fr/fr/nous-contacter-client, https://www.ups.com/fr/fr/help-center/get-started-with-ups.page; again it's a complex process that I wouldn't count on.